# How to apply a single query that sum column for individual values

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables named `user` and `statistics`

`user` table has 3 columns: `id`, `name` and `category`

`statistics` table has 3 columns: `id`, `idUser` (relational), `cal`

something like this:

**user**

```
 Id name  category
 1  name1 1
 2  name2 2
 3  name3 3
```

**statistics**

```
Id idUser cal
1  1      1
2  1      1
3  1      1
4  2      1
5  2      1
```

How can I apply a query that sum the `cal` column by each category of users and give me something like this:

```
category totalcal
1        3
2        2 
3        0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do a `left join` to keep all the categories.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select u.category, coalesce(sum(s.cal), 0) as cal
from users u left join
     statistics s
     on u.id = s.idUser
group by u.category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to get `0` sum for the `category=3`:

```
SELECT
    user.category
    ,SUM(statistics.cal) AS totalcal
FROM
    user
    LEFT JOIN statistics ON statistics.idUser = user.Id
GROUP BY
    user.category
```

Here `SUM` would return `NULL` for `category=3`. To get `0` instead of `NULL` you can use `COALESCE(SUM(statistics.cal), 0)`.